# Code not executing in docRef.getDocument?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function to check whether an account already exists in the firestore database so that the user can register for one. I have an bool exists to return whether the account exists or not but the code in getDocument() is not executing and assigning the values properly.

```
 func checkAccountExists(username: String) -> Bool {
    let docRef = accountsRef!.document(username)
    var exists: Bool!

    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            exists = true
        } else {
            exists = false
        }
    }

            return exists //Unexpectedly found nil error
}
```

Comment: `docRef.getDocument()` is asynchronous and returns immediate before the query is complete.  The callback will be invoked some time later.  That means your function will return before `exists` has a value.  In fact, you can't make this function return the correct value without blocking the calling thread (which you really don't want to do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only does Doug correctly point out that the function is async, in Swift, you should not attempt a function (or a computed property) that returns an async value. Instead, consider a function with an async completion that passes the value as an argument.

```
func checkAccountExists(username: String, completion: @escaping (_ exists: Bool) -> Void) {
    accountsRef!.document(username).getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document,
            document.exists {
            completion(true)
        } else {
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
checkAccountExists(username: someUsername) { (exists) in
    if exists {
        print("user exists")
    } else {
        print("user doesn't exist or there was an error")
    }
}
```

However, since the database could return an error (even if the user exists), consider returning a `Result` instead of a `Bool`. But if you just want a pass/fail mechanism that doesn't decipher between errors and a user truly not existing, this will work.